# I cannot use SHL (shift left) with int64 variables

Tags: delphi

```
 Result:= b8;
 Result:= Result+ (b7  SHL  8);
 Result:= Result+ (b6  SHL 16);
 Result:= Result+ (b5  SHL 24);
 Result:= Result+ (b4  SHL 32);
 Result:= Result+ (b3  SHL 40);      <------ here
 Result:= Result+ (b2  SHL 48);
 Result:= Result+ (MSB SHL 56);
```

(Result is int64 and b1-b8 is byte).

But the compiler complains about "constant exp violates subrange bounds".
Then I have found this warning "The compiler will reject hardcoded shift right values that exceed 32, unless the data type is Int64. The same is not true for Shl" on a web site. Delphi Help says nothing about it. Why is there a limit? Can I stop it? Maybe a compiler directive or something? I can use a multiplication to get over it, but it will be slower. There is a faster way to do it?

Edit:
I am thinking also in creating two cardinals because I can use SHL on cardinals, then to merge the cardinals together. This will require only one multiplication. Any other ideas?

Edit2: 
The code is part of an algorithm that converts a number form base 255 to base 256 (and the other way around). I do this 50000 million times; so speed is important.

Comment: Result is a Int64-type? And b3 also? Can you insert a typecast to Int64: Int64(b3)?

Comment: Sorry. Sorry. I totally forgot about that. I updated my question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'd avoid all arithmetic (your code has additions and shifts) and do it like this:

```
Int64Rec(Result).Bytes[0] := b8;
Int64Rec(Result).Bytes[1] := b7;
//etc.
```

`Int64Rec` is defined in SysUtils like this:

```
Int64Rec = packed record
  case Integer of
    0: (Lo, Hi: Cardinal);
    1: (Cardinals: array [0..1] of Cardinal);
    2: (Words: array [0..3] of Word);
    3: (Bytes: array [0..7] of Byte);
end;
```

If you stored your bytes in an array then you could wrap it all up in a `for` loop.

Comment: @TOndrej My comment was intended to find that out.

Comment: Don't worry, you have +1 from me. This will put your post back to a positive value. I don't see nothing wrong with your answer.

Comment: Edite: Hi David. Initially, I have marked your answer as 'accepted' but them I marked TOndrej's answer as accepted since he answer my specific question about compiler's strange behavior and show hot to overcome it. HOWEVER, I use your solution in my code since it is indeed elegant.

Comment: @Altar Whatever. I don't buy the idea that you must answer the question that is asked. It is my experience in development that the hardest part is working out what the right question is. So I always try to consider alternative approaches to any problem. That's how I do it when I am doing my day job and I see no reason to change tack on SO.

Comment: Both answers helped me. However, StackOverflow does not allow me to mark more than one answer as 'accepted'. This will be a nice addition to StackOverflow. What I can do is to create a new question that asks for a faster algorithm (yours) not also what's causing the problem so you can post your answer and I mark it as accepted.

Comment: EDIT: I have removed again the 'accepted' mark. Since I can mark only one answer as 'accepted' I wait one week. The answer that gets most votes will be marked as accepted. So, this way the readers will decide who gets the points and not me. Alternatively, maybe there is a moderator that can mark both answers as 'accepted'.

Comment: @Altar There's no need to create a new question, and I accepted your reasoning for the accept on the other answer. You've not offended me.  Mostly I feel sad that the inelegant code gets the tick next to it which might encourage other developers to continue to use shifts and magic constants to solve such problems. The accepted answer would be much better if it actually went into some details as to why the compiler behaves as it does (and it does so for very good reasons) and explained that there are more elegant ways to achieve this particular goal.

Comment: +1 For elegance, shl has its uses, but this is not one of them, your code is far superior.

Comment: Nice one.. easy to read, and it should be fast.. If your code needs to be portable, I guess you need to keep endian-ness in count here, right?

Comment: @wouter yes that's true. I've never coded for big endian machine. I've no experience of the common techniques to handle it.

Comment: As promised, I marked the most voted question as 'accepted'. Thanks a lot for your solution.

Comment: Fantastic answer! I had a similar problem, but by using Int64Rec I could reduce 10 lines of complex ands, ors and shls to two lines of simple and elegant code.

Answer (score 11):

I'm assuming that your `Result` is `Int64` already, and `b8`, `b7` and so on are declared as `Byte`. The compiler needs a little help. Typecast to `Int64`:

```
  Result := b8;
  Result := Result + (b7 shl  8);
  Result := Result + (b6 shl 16);
  Result := Result + (b5 shl 24);
  Result := Result + (Int64(b4) shl 32);
  Result := Result + (Int64(b3) shl 40);
  Result := Result + (Int64(b2) shl 48);
  Result := Result + (Int64(msb) shl 56);
```

Comment: I still have a violently allergic reaction to this solution. I agree that it can work but why use all this arithmetic, bit shifting, magic constants? Surely it's best to assign each byte directly?  I cannot endorse code like this when elegant options exist.

Comment: Yes but the question was about shl specifically.

Comment: @David : This is absolutely the correct answer to the question posed. I'd agree it's possible that a different question should have been asked, but maybe the code snippet was just a poor choice to show the SHL problem?

Comment: @TOndrej But OP even expressed concern about performance. It's hard to imagine that memory copy + int64 arithmetic can be faster than plain memory copy.

Comment: @Roddy Perhaps that's true.  I doubt it though.

Comment: The concern about performance is moot since we don't know the context or even the intended goal. I just answered the specific question about shl since I didn't feel like playing Columbo today. ;-)

Comment: @TOndrej I have rescinded my downvote.  This code revolts me but I've made those feelings clear enough in the comments!

Comment: Thanks to all. Please see my updated question. It explains why speed is important.

Comment: Thanks TOndrej. Now I see how we can 'help' the compiler. Isn't this compiler protection strange (especially that it is undocumented)?

Comment: Thanks TOndrej. Now I see how we can 'help' the compiler. Why the compiler behaves like this?

Comment: +1 for correct answer to "how to shoot myself in the foot using shl", But -2 for not including warnings in the answer about how error prone this is.

Answer (score 8):

Here is another solution that uses shifts but I believe is "cleaner" (though not as clean as David's suggestion):

```
result := MSB;
result := (result shl 8) or b2;  { could use "shl sizeof(b2)" instead of 8 }
result := (result shl 8) or b3;
etc
result := (result shl 8) or b8;
```

this solution avoids all the "magic" shifting values and it is probably easier to understand.  Also, if MSB..b8 (or b1..b8) were an array of bytes, the above code could easily be converted into a single line loop.

To answer your question as to why the compiler does not accept the value 40 and above, the reason is most likely due to this quote from Volume 2B of the Intel Instruction Set Reference for the SHLD instruction:

> In non-64-bit modes and default 64-bit
>   mode; only bits 0 through 4 of the
>   count are used. This masks the count
>   to a value between 0 and 31. If a
>   count is greater than the operand
>   size, the result is undefined.

The equivalent condition on the SHL instruction is not quite as stringent:

> The 8086 does not mask the shift
>   count. However, all other IA-32
>   processors (starting with the Intel
>   286 processor) do mask the shift count
>   to 5 bits, resulting in a maximum
>   count of 31. This masking is done in
>   all operating modes (including the
>   virtual-8086 mode) to reduce the
>   maximum execution time of the
>   instructions.

In either case, a value greater than 31 is either useless (when using SHL) or undefined (when using SHLD).  The compiler obviously knows this and, it is preventing you from writing code that is potentially erroneous (in 64 bit mode.)

if you, indeed are doing this operation 50 BILLION times, then you may want to consider doing it in inline assembly, which would be quite simple:

```
asm
    xor eax, eax   
    or  eax, MSB   { or b1 depending on how you named the MSB }
    shl eax, 8
    or  eax, b2
    shl eax, 8
    or  eax, b3
    shl eax, 8
    or  eax, b4
    mov High32bit, eax
end;
```

and repeat the above operation for the low 32 bit dword and b5 thru b8.  I didn't suggest using SHLD because I don't believe Delphi supports the 64 bit registers nor 64bit instructions (I could be wrong, I've never tried it.)

Note: I've heard rumors that the 64bit version of Delphi will not support inline assembly.  This may or may not be the case but, I would stay away from inline assembly unless it is truly absolutely necessary.

Hope that helps,

John.

PS: there is another reason why David Heffernan's solution is the best one. In the solution I presented, every instruction depends on the previous instruction (that is, eax must be shifted by 8 before the next "or" instruction can be executed).  David's solution sets individual bytes, as such, each assignment is independent of the previous assignment, this will allow the processor to potentially carry out multiple assignments in parallel.  In this era of multi-core processors this has the potential of being quite a bit faster than the assembly code I gave as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a function to convert a Integer to int64bit:
example: AData = 36 --> Bit 36 will be set etc

```
uses SysUtils;

[...]

function IntegertoInt64Bit(AData : Integer): UInt64;
  var
    idx : integer;
  begin
    result := 0;
    for idx := 7 downto 0 do
    begin
      if(AData >= idx * 8) then
      begin
        Int64Rec(result).Bytes[idx] := 1 shl ((AData-1) mod 8);
        break;
      end;
    end;
  end;
```